# How to disable space in input type="text"

Tags: html

Can someone show me an example of how i can edit the below code to disable or remove space when typing in input type="text field.

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="{{ \App\getAllClasses()['text'] }}" placeholder="Username">
```

I tried to to find a similar script but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the spaces in the input field like this:

```
<input
  type="text"
  id="username"
  name="username"
  class="{{ \App\getAllClasses()['text'] }}"
  placeholder="Username"
  onkeypress="return event.charCode != 32"
>
```

The `onkeypress` event handler checks the ASCII code of the character being typed, and if it's 32 (the ASCII code for the space character), it returns `false`, which means the space won't be entered into the input field.

Comment: Note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I was working a lot with JSX lately and added it not on purpose.